# Dynamic bezier curve creation C++

Tags: c++, ios, cocos2d-x, bezier

I'm trying to imitate the drawing of lines in a certain [iOS game](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MADHFGcmKFs) on `cocos2dx`,

The way i chose to implement it is by creating a dynamic cubic bezier curve.
For that, i will have to get 4 x-y screen locations:

1) begin point

2) control point 1

3) control point 2

4) ending point

As for the begin and end points, it's obvious i should use `onTouchBegan` and `onTouchEnded` and retrieve the relevant locations.

Since the line should be drawn immediately meaning, not drawing the non processed line and then process it, but creating a temp bezier curve at any time, i don't really know how to approach it and create the curve.

```
onTouchMoved(cocos2d::Touch *Touch, cocos2d::Event *Event)
```

is the problematic part, how do i determine the relevant control points?

any suggestions or ideas for different implementation will be welcomed.

Cheers.

Comment: It would probably be easier to use a [cubic spline](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubicSpline.html) as then you can define it in terms of control points lying on the curve which your users could then presumably move more intuitively.

Comment: well after a short reading session, i totally agree. thanks for the idea man :)